# Does the HERE Android SDK make use of compass sensor to determine the heading?

Tags: android, here-api

Does the heading calculated as part of GeoPosition work correctly if the device does not have a compass?

The only reference I found to the device sensors in the HERE Android SDK docs was about `GeoPosition#getPositionTechnology`. I'm looking for information about what sensors are actually used and what happens if a particular sensor like compass is unavailable on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of ways which enables to collect data, like 
GeoPosition.TECHNOLOGY_WIFI, GeoPosition.TECHNOLOGY_CELL, GeoPosition.TECHNOLOGY_BLE, GeoPosition.TECHNOLOGY_GNSS

For more detailed methods and fields, kindly refer : 
developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/GeoPosition.html#TECHNOLOGY_WIFI

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. This doesn't answer the question about what happens if a sensor is unavailable on a phone though.

Comment: Any updates on this? What happens if a device has compass missing?